# Problem Downloading ggplot on Rstudio on a mac

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using a macbook and trying to download ggplot2 using

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
```

but the following error keep popping up

```
* installing *source* package ‘scales’ ...
** package ‘scales’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘colorspace’
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘scales’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/scales’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘scales’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘scales’ is not available for package ‘ggplot2’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/ggplot2’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/gr/_lps4tvd06gd53snb_q3kgn80000gn/T/Rtmp56qAqb/downloaded_packages’
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Try `install.packages("colorspace")` first.

Comment: Also consider updating R.